# プライバシーポリシー画面設置方法(Google Apps Developersからのメール)

Tags: google-apps-script

ご教示お願い致します。質問が3つあります。

【前提】
当方、
・自作のTwitter botと連携
・自GoogleアカウントのGmailアドレスから発信
・自GoogleアカウントのGoogle Drive上のファイルの読み書き
等を行うGoogle Apps Scriptのプロジェクトを保持しております。

Google Apps Developers から以下の内容のメールを受信しました。

> Hi Google API Developer,
>
> We sent this email because you’re listed as a contact on the following
>   Google Cloud Project(s) using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs:
>
> project-id-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(固有のID①が入ります)
>   project-id-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy(固有のID②が入ります) In October 2018, we
>   announced that, in January 2019, new Gmail API policies for restricted
>   scopes will go into effect. We want to let you know that, starting
>   today, you can submit your app(s) that use restricted scopes for
>   verification. Please review the full policy and OAuth FAQ for more
>   information including the secure handling requirement.
>
> What you need to do If you want to use one of the restricted scopes,
>   for verification through the Google API Console (On the left side menu
>   click Credentials, then click OAuth consent screen) between January
>   16th and February 15th, 2019 for the project(s) listed above. Owners
>   and editors of the project will be able to submit for verification and
>   developers with internal apps for users in the same G Suite domain do
>   not need to do this.
>
> If you do not take action If you do not submit for verification by
>   February 15th, 2019, we’ll disable account access for new users on
>   February 22nd, 2019.
>
> If you do not submit for verification by March 31st, 2019, we’ll
>   revoke existing consumer grants.
>
> Thanks, Google Cloud Platform/API Trust & Safety

案内に従って、Google Cloud Platformを開き、[認証情報]>[OAuth同意画面]を開き、[確認のため送信]を押すと、以下の画像の通り、
「[アプリケーション ホームページ]リンク」と「[アプリケーション プライバシー ポリシー]」が必須というエラーになりました。
[image: 「認証情報画面]

====================

### 【質問①】

現状、「[アプリケーション ホームページ]リンク」と「[アプリケーション プライバシー ポリシー]」に該当するサイトを保持していないのですが、作成しないとGoogle Apps Scriptのプロジェクトが停止してしまうという事になりますでしょうか。

### 【質問②】

作成する必要がある場合、Googleドライブ上の何らかのサービスを使用して作成できるのでしょうか。

### 【質問③】

サイトを作成した場合、Google Apps Scriptとどのように関連付ければ良いのでしょうか。

初歩的な質問かもしれず、申し訳ありません。
ご教示お願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/124718/please-tell-me-about-how-to-implement-privacy-policy-site-for-my-google-apps-scr?answertab=votes#tab-top
上記のサイトで回答してくださった方がいました。
感謝申し上げます。

頂いた回答をGengoさんで翻訳して頂きました。
(翻訳して頂いた内容を載せる事は問題ないとの事です)

---

問題は、あなたのユーザーが許可を承認する際に、警告メッセージが表示されるかどうかということです。Googleにより承認または確認されているか否かに関わらず、あなたはApps Scriptプロジェクトを公開し、利用することができます。例えプライバシーポリシーを公に表示していなくても、あるいはプロジェクトがGoogleによって確認されていなくても、あなたのプロジェクトが動作しなくなることはないでしょう。また、もしそのプロジェクトの目的があなたのプライベートな利用だけなら、確認プロセスを通過するとなるとより多くのことや、より多くの面倒に対処する必要が出てきます。従って、確認プロセスを通過したいかどうかは、おそらくあなたが外部のユーザーを持っているかどうかということに左右されます。あなただけが利用するプロジェクトに対してプライベートポリシーを掲載するのは無意味です。

もしあなたのプロジェクトが公開アドオンであるなら、ユーザーにはあなたのアドオンが安全ではないという警告メッセージを見せたくないでしょう。それが、開発者が確認プロセスを通し、ウェブサイトを作成して、プライバシーポリシーとサービス規約を公表する理由の1つです。

もしあなたがプライバシーポリシーを公に掲載したいなら、最も簡単な方法はGoogle Siteを使うことです。無料で利用でき、Google Siteを立ち上げて比較的簡単に機能させることができます。

もしあなたが外部ユーザーを持っているなら、ドメイン名を持ったサイトを持ちたいかもしれません。その場合、年間12ドルでGoogle Domainsからドメイン名を購入することができます。G Suiteアカウントを持っていれば、自分のGoogle Siteにドメイン名を関連付けることができます。もちろん、どんなドメイン名販売業者やホスティングサイトを使っても、プライバシーポリシーとサービス規約を掲載することができます。

プロジェクトとプライバシーポリシーの関連付けは、Google Cloud Platform内で行います。

あらゆるApps ScriptプロジェクトはプロジェクトIDを持っており、Google Cloud Platformに登録されています。Google Cloud Platformに直接行き、プロジェクトを選ぶことができます：

https://console.cloud.google.com/home

あるいは、Apps Scriptコードエディタでプロジェクトを開いて、「リソース」メニューをクリックし、「Cloud Platformプロジェクト」メニュー項目をクリックして、青色のリンクをクリックすることで、直接自分のプロジェクトに行くことができます。私からは、常にコードエディタを通すことをお勧めします。なぜなら、一部の設定はコードエディタを通さないと正しく表示されないからです。

ウェブサイトを確認する
ウェブサイトを作成する
Search Consoleを開く：https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en
Search Consoleには「新しい」ものと古いものがあります
Search Consoleに新しい「プロパティ」（ウェブサイトURL）を追加
これはGoogleに対しあなた自身のウェブサイトであることを確認および証明します
あなたのウェブサイトをCloud Platformプロジェクトに追加するためには、確認を行う必要があります
ウェブサイトを「ドメインの確認」に追加する
上部左側のメニューで、ナビゲーションメニューを開く
「APIとサービス」の上にカーソルを置き、「認証情報」をクリックする
「ドメインの確認」タブをクリックする
プライバシーポリシーとプロジェクトを関連付ける
「APIとサービス」セクションから「OAuth同意画面」タブをクリックする
「承認済みドメイン」の欄があるので、自分のウェブサイトURLをそこに入力してください。
ホームページへのリンク、プライバシープライバシーのリンク、およびサービス規約（TOS）のリンクを入力してください。
その他の必要な欄を全て入力する
「保存」をクリック
何か誤りがあることを示すエラーメッセージが表示されていないことを確認してください
Appsscript.jsonマニフェストファイルで異なるメールスコープを手動設定することで、あなたがセンシティブなスコープで使用中のメールの受け取りを回避することができます。Apps Scriptコードエディタの「表示」メニューをクリックしてから、「マニフェストファイルを表示」をクリックする必要があります。もしメールを送りたいだけなら、全てのGmailAppサービスのクラス名をMailAppに変更し、次のスコープをAppsscript.jsonマニフェストファイルに入力してください。

"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"
Example Manifest - appsscript.json
{
  "timeZone": "Etc/GMT",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
  ],

"exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
全ての必要なスコープをマニフェストファイルに追加したことを確認する必要があります。使用されている既存のスコープは次の手順で見られます：ファイル -> プロジェクトのプロパティ -> スコープ

既存の全てのメールスコープを確実に削除し、https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send で置き換えてください。

スコープ「https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send」は、Googleからの特別な確認を必要としません。なぜなら、あなたのアクセスはメールの送信のみに制限されており、メールの閲覧、作成、削除、またはメール設定は利用できないからです。